# Which standard deviation to use for sample size calculation of paired t-test

Tags: standard-deviation, sample-size, paired-data

I am interested in calculating the sample size required for a paired t-test, with alpha=0.05 and power=0.8. I understand that the formula n= 1 + 2(7.85)(s/d)^2 could be used, where n is the sample size, d is the difference to be detected and s is the standard deviation.

However, I am not very sure which standard deviation is it referring to. May I hence enquire it is the standard deviation of the variable before the intervention or after the intervention, or is it the pooled standard deviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are analyzing the paired difference which under the null hypothesis is N(0, $\sigma^2$). So it is the variance and standard deviation of the paired difference that you want to use.